# Can I Avoid Ambushes with a High Enough Agility

Tags: final-fantasy-10

[This link](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/197344-final-fantasy-x/faqs/31381) mentions Initial Counter Value as being a sub-stat derived from the Agility Stat which determines who acts first in a battle.

I'm trying to read and understand what it's describing, but I'm just not getting it.

I see that Initial Counter Value is capped and an Agility Stat greater than 170 doesn't accomplish anything. But say that I do have an Agility Stat of 170, does this mean that I can do away with my First Strike weapon? Will I always go first even when ambushed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many posts like [this one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643146-final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/68908864#4) which associate First Strike and the Agility Stat and the Initial Counter Value specifically. A max Agility Stat is ubiquitously called out as being inferior to First Strike.

The question however is: "In spite of it's inferiority can a max Agility Stat provide a sufficient Initial Counter Value to overcome an ambush?" I can empirically say, *yes* to this, as I have been ambushed by monsters with a low Agility Stat and had my characters, which didn't have First Strike or Initiative weapons, get a turn before the ambusher. However, since we are working under the premise that First Strike is superior to a max Agility Stat, it must be noted that [some monsters have the First Strike ability](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/First_Strike_%28Ability%29):

1. Varuna will always open the battle with Haste
2. Kottos will always open the battle by switching into its Counter status, signified by the raising of its fists
3. Great Malboro enemies fought in the Omega Ruins will always ambush the player using Bad Breath on their first turn, however, a player's First Strike ability precedes this

So even a max Agility Stat, providing the best possible Initial Counter Value, will still be inferior to the Great Malboro's First Strike. I believe you see that called out in posts like [this one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/730650-final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd-remaster/69315574#4), which correctly surmise an answer to this question:

**Agility in excess of 170 only effects the Initial Counter Value, which is pointless against an enemy with First Strike. Only your own First Strike weapon will allow you to take a turn before said enemies.**